# Is it possible to make Instance == string/int/float or any datatype to be True in python?

Tags: python, comparison

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)


example = Element("project", "some project")
```

```py
example == "some project"  # False
```

Is there a way to make above statement `True` rather than

```py
example.value == "some project" # True
```

Comment: Override [`object.__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overloading `__eq__` and `__ne__` operators in your class.

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other

f = Element("some project")
f == "some project" # True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `__eq__()` for your class.

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other


example = Element("project", "some project")
```

This is called "operator overloading" and it allows you to define custom behaviour for builtin operators (in this case the `=` operator).

Bear in mind that both operator precedence and associativity apply.

More on this in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).

Answer (score 1):

yes, as in comment mention you need to override the equals for the class

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class foo:
      def __init__(self, x=0,name=""):
            self.o=x
            self.name=name

      def __eq__(self, other):
             #compare here your fields 
             return self.name==other

if __name__ == "__main__":

    d1 = foo(1,"1")
    d2=foo(1,"2")
    print (d1=="1")

    print ("1"==d1)
```